# Changing the default shortcut in OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, keyboard-shortcuts, tabs

Shift-Command-Tab is for Switch application--cycle backward

Can I change it to just **Shift-Command**? I'm on Snow Leopard.

Comment: not sure it's possible, but doing so would break a great many shortcuts, just a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to set a shortcut key combination using only modifier keys (Shift, Command).